# Set up profileViewController UIImageView & UILabel based on different users

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am making an app at the moment but I am faced with an issue. I am new enough to the world of iOS development so please be patient. In my app a user registers by inputing data into cells in a tableView. e.g name, profile photo etc..

If registration is successful the user is then sent to their home page where I have a UIImageView and a `UIlabel`.

**The issue**
I am wondering how I can make sure that this `UILabel` and `UIImageView` are set according to the user. e.g when user A logs in or registers the `UIImageView` matches the image they used when registering and so on and so forth for userB, userC etc...

Any suggestions would be great and I hope I am clear in what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Where are you storing the data after registration?

Comment: i am sending it to a parse database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the user press the `loginButton` Button in the `resgisterViewController`. You'll have to pass a `NSString` for your `UILabel` and an `UIImage` for you `UIImageView` in the `MainViewController`.

Follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9736559/2053537) (Passing Data Forward) step-by-step on how to do that. You `RegsiterViewController` will be the `ViewControllerA` and `MainViewController` will be `ViewControllerB` in that answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. So just to be clear i can pass the data for UILabel via an NsString variable and then on the homeVC i will just load this NSString to the UILabel on my hone VC. And repeat this for registration process also? Also guys i am using say email for login and i want the UILabel on the homeVC to be equal to the users name that they supplied at registration which is sent to database..

Comment: Will do thanks guys :) i will try this and post if i have issue

Comment: @RaymondSmith Hey ray, I can't really help if I don't know what you've done at all. I suggest you post a new question of your error and show your code and describe things in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `initWithUser:` method for instantiating your `profileViewController`, in which the User object has properties indicating the userName and imageName, for example. On `viewDidLoad` you assign these to your `UIImageView` and `UILabel`.

Answer (score 0):

Fo reducing the confusion you can store the all data locally in some variable or dictionary and then you use the same. To use it on other view controllers just make those variables or dictionary globally accessible.

Comment: that would break the purpose of OOP

Comment: Creation of dictionary is also suggested which he can pass thro' initWithUser: .

Comment: But making stuff globally accessible when they should be passed along is not best practice.

Comment: I appreciate what you say. But that is developer point of view. Whether he is going to need data on one view controller or other view controllers too.